# Why can't UMDH find my symbols? Can I interpret a stack trace without them?

Tags: c++, mfc, symbols, umdh

I'm trying to debug a memory leak using UMDH.  It never successfully loads the symbols, though.  I am pretty sure I have things set up correctly -

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>set _
_NT_SYMBOL_PATH=SRV*C:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;E:\mysymbols

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>dir e:\mysymbols
 Volume in drive E is DataApps
 Volume Serial Number is F6F5-37AE

 Directory of e:\mysymbols

11/08/2012  03:20 PM    <DIR>          .
11/08/2012  03:20 PM    <DIR>          ..
11/08/2012  10:02 AM         2,630,656 Gen2EAPI.pdb
11/08/2012  10:07 AM         4,555,776 ObjectCommunicator.pdb
11/08/2012  10:01 AM         2,475,008 ObjSrvCommAPI.pdb
11/08/2012  10:02 AM         3,761,152 ScpmAPI.pdb
               4 File(s)     13,422,592 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  803,125,231,616 bytes free
```

But UMDH refuses to load the symbols for ObjectCommunicator.exe:

```
// Debug library initialized ...
DBGHELP: ObjectCommunicator - no symbols loaded
DBGHELP: ntdll - public symbols  
        C:\Symbols\ntdll.pdb\F7024C7F15FE4BEA992FF38BE58AC11C2\ntdll.pdb
```

ObjectCommunicator.exe was built with these options (using vc 6.0.  Yeah - it's old, but upgrading isn't an option):

```
/nologo /MD /W3 /GR /GX /Zi /Od /I "..\Scpm Api" /I "..\ScpmImpl" /D "NDEBUG" /D "WIN32" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_AFXDLL" /D "_MBCS" /D MODULE_NAME=\"ObjectCommunicator\" /Fp"Release/ObjectCommunicator.pch" /Yu"stdafx.h" /Fo"Release/" /Fd"Release/" /FD /c
```

And linked with these options (minus some .libs):

```
/nologo /subsystem:windows /incremental:no /pdb:"..\Bin\Release/ObjectCommunicator.pdb" /debug /machine:I386 /out:"..\Bin\Release/ObjectCommunicator.exe" /IGNORE:4089
```

Why would UMDH not be able to load my symbols?  Is there any way to debug that?  And if not, is there any way to interpret a UMDH stack trace like this:

```
+   42432 (  45424 -   2992)    167 allocs  BackTraceAEB
+     156 (    167 -     11)    BackTraceAEB    allocations

ntdll!RtlAllocateHeapSlowly+41
ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+E9F
msvcrt!malloc+6C
MFC42!operator new+15
ObjectCommunicator!???+0 : 402F71
ObjectCommunicator!???+0 : 43D6AC
ObjectCommunicator!???+0 : 43C523
ObjectCommunicator!???+0 : 43C3E4
MFC42!_AfxThreadEntry+FB
msvcrt!_endthreadex+A3
kernel32!BaseThreadStart+34
```

In particular, what does "ObjectCommunicator!???+0 : 43C3E4" mean?  Can I do something with CDB, for example, to turn that into a meaningful reference?

Comment: Never used umdh, but dr. memory might serve you better? it's the closest thing to valgrind that I've used on windows.

Comment: Hard to guess at this.  By all means, *do* use CDB to troubleshoot this.  It uses the same symbol engine as UMDH.  CDB has the -n option to turn on "noisy symbol load".

Comment: CDB can find my symbols - in particular, it appears I can use `ln <address>` to find the symbols in the stack trace from UMDH.  I do get a `*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for C:\Program Files\Datacard\SCS\bin\ObjectCommunicator.exe` message from CDB, but it finds the symbols from e:\mysymbols.  I'm very confused, since I understand that UMDH and CDB use the same symbol finding engine.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, I just needed to do a real install of the Debugging tools.  "Advanced Windows Debugging" claimed that those tools could be installed via a copy, but that doesn't seem to work with UMDH.  After installing using the official installer, I was able to get UMDH to see the symbols.

Comment: This did it.  I was messing with copying over PDBs to my local symbols cache and everything.  It turns out running an installed UMDH is different than a copy, as you state.  +1 and thanks!